# How to everytime reload web, and get the newest data from back-end

Tags: javascript, php

What my purpose is below

Visting a web and the js.file in this web will load php file, and it will return data to html.

It's meaning every time when I reload web, I will get newest data.

---

I have try this in `js.file`

```
let XML = new XMLHttpRequest();
XML.open('post', url, true);
XML.send('mydata');
```

then use responseText to get data I want

Indeed, I **don't need send any data**.

I can do what I want to do, but I am not sure this way is right or not.

Because I think ajax should not use in this case, it must be send something and return something.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are saying is you only want to get data without sending anything which is called a http get request, you can do that as below.

```js
function get(url)
{
    var xm = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // false for synchronous
    xm.open("GET",url,false);
    xm.send(null);
    return xm.responseText;
}
console.log(get('your Url'));
```

You need to specify the url of your Http Endpoint ( Back-End ).

If your are making a asynchronous request then below code works,,

```
function get(theUrl, callback)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
     // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

get('your url',(responseText)=>{
    console.log(responsetext);
});
```